# DataTables jquery plugin not working, get a blank page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatable

I am trying to implement the Datatables jquery plugin on with my html table but having no luck.  I'm linking to the Datatables CDN for both the CSS styling and Datatables script itself, while linking to Google's hosted jquery plugin. I also have a local Javascript file with the script to initialize data tables on my table.  I go to open the html page and just get my plain table as if DataTable isn't even functioning.  What could I be doing wrong?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="datatables.js"></script>

<table id="mytable">
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>High-Level Category</th>
      <th>Device Type</th>
      <th>Hostname</th>
      <th>IP Address</th>
      <th>Owner</th>
      <th>Organizational Unit</th>
      <th>Organizational Unit Email</th>
      <th>Universal Forwarder or Syslog?</th>
      <th>In PCI?</th>
      <th>Notes</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
<tbody contenteditable>
    <tr>
      <td contenteditable="true">SECDEV1</td>
      <td contenteditable="true">Firewall</td>
      <td contenteditable="true">Description 1</td>
      <td contenteditable="true">1.1.1.1</td>
      <td contenteditable="true">Kim</td>
      <td contenteditable="true">Information Technology</td>
      <td contenteditable="true">test@test.com</td>
      <td contenteditable="true">Syslog</td>
      <td contenteditable="true">Yes</td>
      <td contenteditable="true">notes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td contenteditable="true">SECDEV2</td>
      <td contenteditable="true">Switch</td>
      <td contenteditable="true">description2</td>
      <td contenteditable="true">2.2.2.2</td>
      <td contenteditable="true">Bob</td>
      <td contenteditable="true">Information Networking</td>
      <td contenteditable="true">test2@test.com</td>
      <td contenteditable="true">Syslog</td>
      <td contenteditable="true">NO</td>
      <td contenteditable="true">more notes</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

The local js file I have is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#mytable').dataTable();

});
```

Any help would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Why both datatables.js and datatable min.js. remove datatables.js.

Comment: The datatables.js is my local javascript script that initializes DataTables. Is that what the datatables.min.js does from Datatables CDN?

Comment: both are same but min.js is a minified version. just remove it and check it.

Comment: I went ahead and removed the datable.min.js.  Still comes up with the same issue.

Comment: not min.js remove last one datatables.js

Comment: there is no ending table tag only 2 starting tags.

Answer (score 1):

Your html code is incorrect.  There was an **extra open ending** table tag.  I corrected your html below:

```
<table id="mytable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>High-Level Category</th>
          <th>Device Type</th>
          <th>Hostname</th>
          <th>IP Address</th>
          <th>Owner</th>
          <th>Organizational Unit</th>
          <th>Organizational Unit Email</th>
          <th>Universal Forwarder or Syslog?</th>
          <th>In PCI?</th>
          <th>Notes</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
        <tbody contenteditable>
            <tr>
              <td contenteditable="true">SECDEV1</td>
              <td contenteditable="true">Firewall</td>
              <td contenteditable="true">Description 1</td>
              <td contenteditable="true">1.1.1.1</td>
              <td contenteditable="true">Kim</td>
              <td contenteditable="true">Information Technology</td>
              <td contenteditable="true">test@test.com</td>
              <td contenteditable="true">Syslog</td>
              <td contenteditable="true">Yes</td>
              <td contenteditable="true">notes</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td contenteditable="true">SECDEV2</td>
              <td contenteditable="true">Switch</td>
              <td contenteditable="true">description2</td>
              <td contenteditable="true">2.2.2.2</td>
              <td contenteditable="true">Bob</td>
              <td contenteditable="true">Information Networking</td>
              <td contenteditable="true">test2@test.com</td>
              <td contenteditable="true">Syslog</td>
              <td contenteditable="true">NO</td>
              <td contenteditable="true">more notes</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve your expected result, use below CDN libraries

```
<!-- DataTables CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css">

<!-- jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>

<!-- DataTables -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

Codepen- http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/AXyLXO

Comment: @zach , if my answer helped your question, please mark it as answered :)